# passing file from bash script to gnuplot script

Tags: scripts, input, gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot and I am troubled in passing my argument alot,
now I have this simple bash script and a gnuplot script.

in the bash script `plot.sh` I should modify my file then send it to the gnuplot script to be plotted OR I can modify my file and just send a parameter (a number passed from another script $1) to the gnuplot script which identifies which file to be plotted, the problem is neither of the two ways is working, I don't seem to get it right! any help?

here's my bash script plot.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's/ns/;/g' /dev/shm/waitingTime$1.txt
gnuplot -e "filename='/dev/shm/waitingTime$1'" file.gnuplot
```

And here is my gnuplot script called file.gnuplot

```
#!/home/yas/file.gnuplot

set xlabel "start"    
set ylabel "Delay"
set autoscale
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 linecolor rgb "red"
plot<"filename"> using 1:2 w points title "tests"
set terminal postscript portrait enhanced mono dashed lw 1 'Helvetica' 14
set output '/dev/shm/TT.pdf'
pause -1
```

end of file.gnuplot

Comment: Move your "set terminal" and "set output" to before the "plot" line. I am not an expert at gnuplot, but in the scripts I use, that is the order of things. There may be other issues, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the graph to show up on the display and *then* have a copy in the PDF file `/dev/shm/TT.pdf`.

I see two problems here:

1. The instruction for the plot --- you store the file name in `filename`, so ypu should just say

   ```
   plot filename  using 1:2 w points title "tests"
   ```

   without the `<"`...  things.
2. If you want the pdf file you should add a `replot` after the change of terminal and output file (double check you can write in the destination directory).

I have created a file `data.dat` and the file `file.gnuplot`:

```
set xlabel "start"    
set ylabel "Delay"
set autoscale
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 linecolor rgb "red"
plot filename   using 1:2 w points title "tests"
set terminal postscript portrait enhanced mono dashed lw 1 'Helvetica' 14
set output 'TT.pdf'
replot
pause -1
```

And calling it with:

```
gnuplot -e "filename='data.dat'" file.gnuplot
```

I have the output:

[image]

...and the corresponding `TT.pdf` file.

By the way, instead of the `pause` at the end, I find much better to add

```
set terminal wxt persist
```

at the start, and remove the pause. The script will finish naturally and the window with the graph will stay put until you dismiss it.